# Is it possible to call Git or other command line tools from inside a Thor script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rake, thor

I find that I'm often running a sequence of routine 'cleanup' tasks before and after I make a git commit for my Rails 3 app.

I was thinking about putting these things into a Thor script, but one thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to use Thor (or Rake) to call other tools on the system.

Is it possible to call a command like `git log` from a Thor or Rake script, and if so what does that look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just shell out:

```
result = %x(git log)
puts result
```

or

```
system('git log')
```

if you just want to pass the output to the terminal.

There is also the [grit](https://github.com/mojombo/grit) gem that abstracts the Git tools into a Ruby library:

```
require 'grit'
repo = Grit::Repo.new("/path/to/repo")
repo.commits.each do |commit|
  puts "#{commit.id}: #{commit.message}"
end
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks. "shell out" is probably the keyword I was lacking in my google quest :)

Comment: Hmm, I get nil returned using %x, system and back-ticks. Is there anything that I am missing? Do I need to cd into the proper directory?

Comment: @Jorge you need to be in or below the project directory (the one with the `.git` directory) and the `git` command must be in the path (i.e. you must make sure your script can actually find `git`).

Comment: It should be noted that Grit doesn't currently work on Windows because of a problem with one of it's dependencies not being supported on the platform. https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn/issues/9

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that those are just Ruby files, so you can use everything in the Ruby arsenal there as well, so things like %x[rm -rf /], [system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441)("rm -rf /") and `rm -rf /` are accessible in those scripts too.