# Rails: access git email config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-config

We have a mail interceptor in our local environment, so that email aren't sent to the actual mail addresses, but a copy is sent to the developpers (devs@project.com).

It is cool, except that all the developpers receive the mails of the whole team, which can be annoying, disturbing.

I'd like to filter with each one using his own email address. I thought of using the git email address, which is set by all of us.

Can my Rails code have an access to this mail address?

Otherwise, I'll create a .gitignored file that each of us should set, but that's more setup then.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: [Is it possible to call Git or other command line tools from inside a Thor script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801920/is-it-possible-to-call-git-or-other-command-line-tools-from-inside-a-thor-script)

```
mail = %x(git config user.email)
```

So the whole interceptor would be:

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)

    git_email = %x(git config user.email)
    filter_email = !git_email.empty? git_email : 'devs@project.com'

    if Rails.env.development? && !message.to.include?(filter_email)
      message.subject = "[Local Filter] To: #{message.to} - #{message.subject}"
      message.to = filter_email 
    end

    return message
  end
end
```